# Trying to login to facebook, but it doesn't get in

Tags: python, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

when i am running the code, it works without errors, but i notice that it really doesn't logins to Facebook and posts a post that says "Hello world". Once it was logined and never after.
I used graph API.

would love to get some help. Thanks

```
import urllib2, cookielib, re, os, sys
from facepy import GraphAPI
import facebook


class Facebook:
    def __init__(self, email, password):

        self.email = email
        self.password = password

        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        opener.add_headers = [('Referer', 'http://login.facebook.com/login.php'),
                             ('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                             ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/8.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7'),
                             'Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)']

        self.opener = opener

    def login(self):

        url = 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php'
        data = "locale=en_US&non_com_login=&email=" + self.email + "&pass="+ self.password + "&lsd=20TOl"


        usock = self.opener.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
        usock = self.opener.open(url, data)

        read = usock.read()

        if "Logout" in read:
            print "Logged in."
            graph = facebook.GraphAPI(Access Token)
            graph.put_object("me", "feed", post="Hello, World!")
        else:
            print "failed login"
            print read
            sys.exit()
        print read

f = Facebook("email", "password")
f.login()


nik = graph.fql('select uid, name, friends from user where uid in'
                '(select first_name, middle_name, last_name '
                'from friend where uid1 = me())')
print nik
```

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. Give a [mcve] and a better problem description than *"it fails"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look up some facebook docs, there might be an API for that. But I tried to login facebook with requests anyway, but it was pain. If your goal is only to login easily to facebook, you can simply use the webdriver from selenium, which works fine. 
Here is a snippet which might get you started:

```
from selenium import webdriver

EMAIL='yourmail'
PASSWORD='yourpassword'
url = 'https://de-de.facebook.com/login/'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(EMAIL)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(PASSWORD)
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').submit()
```

For testing purposes you can use the `webdriver.Firefox()` instead of `PhantomJS()`
Once your logged in you can also switch to a requests session, which might be faster. (Therefore you need to `import requests`)

```
session = requests.session()
cook = {i['name']: i['value'] for i in driver.get_cookies()}
#transfer cookies to new session
requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(session.cookies, cook)
driver.quit()
```